# Locked out of my Ubuntu Server while enabling UFW. I am booted in rescue mode and now I am not sure what to do. I am not used to command line

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I got locked out of my server when enabling UFW. I am running latest Ubuntu. I am not familiar with using Ubuntu, I have booted it in rescue mode.

`fdisk -L` gives me:

```
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram1: 50 MiB, 52428800 bytes, 102400 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram2: 50 MiB, 52428800 bytes, 102400 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram3: 50 MiB, 52428800 bytes, 102400 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram4: 50 MiB, 52428800 bytes, 102400 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram5: 50 MiB, 52428800 bytes, 102400 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram6: 50 MiB, 52428800 bytes, 102400 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram7: 50 MiB, 52428800 bytes, 102400 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram8: 50 MiB, 52428800 bytes, 102400 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram9: 50 MiB, 52428800 bytes, 102400 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram10: 50 MiB, 52428800 bytes, 102400 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram11: 50 MiB, 52428800 bytes, 102400 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram12: 50 MiB, 52428800 bytes, 102400 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram13: 50 MiB, 52428800 bytes, 102400 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram14: 50 MiB, 52428800 bytes, 102400 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram15: 50 MiB, 52428800 bytes, 102400 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/nvme1n1: 477 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Disk model: SAMSUNG MZVL2512HCJQ-00B07              
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: B84C1C45-D51F-446A-BCA5-40101BCEE031

Device             Start        End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/nvme1n1p1      2048    1048575   1046528  511M EFI System
/dev/nvme1n1p2   1048576  999161855 998113280  476G Linux RAID
/dev/nvme1n1p3 999161856 1000210431   1048576  512M Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 477 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Disk model: SAMSUNG MZVL2512HCJQ-00B07              
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 0237B914-6B0A-426B-BA60-29764BFA9952

Device              Start        End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1       2048    1048575   1046528  511M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2    1048576  999161855 998113280  476G Linux RAID
/dev/nvme0n1p3  999161856 1000210431   1048576  512M Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p4 1000211120 1000215182      4063    2M Linux filesystem
```

How can I get back in the server? I am a completely newbie in command line, help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try at terminal:
sudo ufw disable

then
reboot